# Align array from map() to rows and columns

Tags: reactjs, grid, react-bootstrap

I created an array of numbers and I used the map() to display it. But I want to align it in 9 rows and 5 columns. Example display in the picture (don't consider the labels of the checkboxes. I just want to sort the checkboxes like that).

[image: This is the example]

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Row , Form, Container} from 'react-bootstrap';

const KlassiSelector = () => {
    const ArrayKlassis = [];
    for(let i=1; i<46; i++){
        ArrayKlassis.push(i);
    }

    return (
            <Row className="m-2">

                <div key="Klassis-Section" className="m-2 justify-content-md-center">
                
                {ArrayKlassis.map((item, index) => (
                    <Form.Check inline label={`${index+1}`} name="group1" type="checkbox" id={`inline-checkbox-${index+1}`}/>
                ))}
                </div>

            </Row>
    );
};

export default KlassiSelector;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import { Row, Form, Container } from "react-bootstrap";

const KlassiSelector = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {[...new Array(9)].map((row, rowIndex) => {
        return (
          <Row className="m-2" key={rowIndex}>
            <div
              key="Klassis-Section"
              className="m-2 justify-content-md-center"
            >
              {[...new Array(5)].map((col, colIndex) => {
                const crrIndex = rowIndex + colIndex * 9 + 1;
                return (
                  <Form.Check
                    key={colIndex}
                    inline
                    label={`${crrIndex}`}
                    name="group1"
                    type="checkbox"
                    id={`inline-checkbox-${crrIndex}`}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </Row>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default KlassiSelector;
```

Hope this would be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. This is totally it. So basically I needed 2 maps to sort out my problem. Your solution is great! Thank you again for your time!